# String literal in compound literal

Tags: c

I have a question about string literals inside compound literals.

As the lifetime of the struct S compound literal is inside the block surrounding the func call, I wonder if it still alright to use the name pointer inside the global gs variable. I guess the string literal "foo" is not bound to the lifetime of the compound literal but rather resides in .rodata? Is that right? At least gs.name still prints foo.

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct S
{
    const char *name;
    int size;
};    

static struct S gs;

static void func(struct S *s)
{
    gs = *s;
}

int main(void)
{
    {
        func(&(struct S){.name="foo",.size=20});
    }

    printf("name: %s size: %d\n", gs.name, gs.size);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, it is fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I guess the string literal "foo" is not bound to the lifetime of the compound literal but rather resides in .rodata?

Yes. That is correct. In

```
 func(&(struct S){.name="foo",.size=20});
```

where `"foo"` initializes a pointer, it's almost as if you had written (if that could be written in C):

```
 func(&(struct S){.name=(static const char[]){'f','o','o','\0'},.size=20});
```

(C doesn't technically allow `static` on compound literals, and C's string literals are really de-facto const-char-arrays, but their formal type is `char[]` without the `const` (for weird historical reasons)).

But be careful with it. In C, you can use string literals to initialize arrays, and if `.name` were an member array, then storing "it" (its decayed pointer) to a global variable would be ill-advised.

Comment: They can be arrays or not. Example: https://godbolt.org/z/K4esE8fqT And the literal is not stored in rodata as well

Comment: C23 is going to allow `static` storage for compound literals

Comment: @0___________  Compilers are like Schroedinger's boxes. It's both an array and not an array until somebody decides to pass its address, and then it is an array -- though perhaps one merged with the array of another string literal if they have the same contents or one is a suffix of the other.